# Get the all links inside the main link and I want to check the all links status. It is not checking the all links

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class GetAllLinks {

  WebDriver driver;
  HttpURLConnection conn=null;
  //HashMap<Integer, String> links = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
  @Test
  public void getLinks() throws InterruptedException, IOException{

      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      //driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      driver.get("http://54.169.220.31");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-target='#login']")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("email_login")).sendKeys("data@gmail.com");
      driver.findElement(By.id("password_login")).sendKeys("12345678");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login_form']/button")).click();

      Thread.sleep(10000);

      List<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<String>();

      List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
      elements.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("img")));
      for(WebElement ele : elements){
        //Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("href"));
        listOfNames.add(ele.getAttribute("href"));
      }
      System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
      System.out.println(listOfNames);

    Object[] st = listOfNames.toArray();
    for(Object s : st){
        if(listOfNames.indexOf(s)!=listOfNames.lastIndexOf(s)){
            listOfNames.remove(listOfNames.lastIndexOf(s));
        }


    }
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
    //System.out.println(listOfNames);

    for(int i=0; i<listOfNames.size();i++){

        if(listOfNames.get(i)!=null){
            if(listOfNames.get(i).startsWith("http")){
                System.out.println(listOfNames.get(i));
                //driver.get(listOfNames.get(i));
                CheckingLink(listOfNames.get(i));
                //return listOfNames.get(i);
                //Thread.sleep(7000);

        }
        }


    }
    //return "";
}

public void CheckingLink(String URL) throws InterruptedException, IOException{

    driver.navigate().to(URL);
    Thread.sleep(20000);

    List<WebElement> listOfaTag = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    listOfaTag.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("img")));

    System.out.println(listOfaTag.size());
    //int count=0;
    for (WebElement lst : listOfaTag) {

            if (lst.getAttribute("href")!=null) {
                //links.put(count, lst.getAttribute("href"));
                System.out.println(lst.getAttribute("href"));
                check_Status(lst.getAttribute("href"));
                //count++;
            }
    }
}


private void check_Status(String attribute) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    if (attribute.startsWith("http")) {
        URL url = new URL(attribute);

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        try {
            conn.connect();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            // System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(
                        attribute + "->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + conn.getResponseCode());

            } else if (conn.getResponseCode() == 500) {
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(
                        attribute + "->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + conn.getResponseCode());

            } else if (conn.getResponseCode() == 404) {
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(
                        attribute + "->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + conn.getResponseCode());

            } else if (conn.getResponseCode() == 402) {
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(
                        attribute + "->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + conn.getResponseCode());

            } else {
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(
                        attribute + "->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + conn.getResponseCode());

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    } 
    //else {
        //System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
        //System.out.println(
        //      attribute + "->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + conn.getResponseCode());

    //}

}


}
```

Above code is not checking the all links. Suddenly it is stopping. It is not given any error. I want to check the all link status.Get the all links inside the main link and I want to check the all links status. It is not checking the all links.

Comment: I have executed the code in my machine and it works fine. You have mentioned it not checking for all links. Can you detail it please?

Comment: @Jakay Can you consider updating us on which page are you trying to check the links?

Comment: I want to get all links in every pages in a website. for example (facebook having n no.of links in every pages)
Note : Instead of check the single page.Script automatically navigate to every page and get the link and add the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Assuming that you want to login in the website with a valid credential & check the status of all the links you can take help of this code block:

```
public class Q44501706_all_links_status 
{

          WebDriver driver;
          HttpURLConnection conn=null;
          @Test
          public void getLinks() throws InterruptedException, IOException
          {
              System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
              driver = new FirefoxDriver();
              driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              driver.get("http://54.169.220.31");
              driver.manage().window().maximize();
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-target='#login']")).click();
              WebElement email_login = driver.findElement(By.id("email_login"));
              WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
              wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(email_login));
              email_login.sendKeys("data@gmail.com");
              driver.findElement(By.id("password_login")).sendKeys("12345678");
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login_form']/button")).click();
              Thread.sleep(10000);
              List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
              System.out.println("Number of WebElements on this page : "+elements.size());
              for (int i=0;i<elements.size();i++)
                {
                    WebElement ele = elements.get(i);
                    String url = ele.getAttribute("href");
                    CheckingLink(url);
                }

        }

        private void CheckingLink(String linkURL) 
        {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(linkURL);
                    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpUrlConnect.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                    httpUrlConnect.connect();
                    if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == 200) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(linkURL + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage());
                    }

                    if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == 500) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(linkURL + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage());
                    }

                    if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == 404) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(linkURL + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage());
                    }

                    if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == 402) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(linkURL + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage());
                    }

                    if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == httpUrlConnect.HTTP_NOT_FOUND) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(
                                linkURL + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage() + " - " + httpUrlConnect.HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }

            } 
}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks you Debanjan. Above code is checking single page only. But i want to check the each and every page link (entire page link). Not only single page.

Comment: @Jakay You can browse to any page & call the function any time to check the status of all the links present on the page.